# Install Codeigniter in subfolder, ignore subfolder part in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, bonfire

I wish to install my Codeigniter Bonfire application in 2 folders one is "en" other is "sl" (both will have different languages and different databases).

So far my first or main controller or how is it called is located in a public directory: `root/sl/public/index.php` and states:

```
$path = "..";
$bonfire_path = "${path}/bonfire";
```

and my .htaccess looks like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* sl/index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Everything works fine if the public directory exists in root folder but when I want it to move to "sl" folder and I type "localhost/sl" in my URL field I get:

```
The requested URL /public/ was not found on this server.
```

So I tried fixing my .htaccess a bit and added `ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ sl/public/$1 [L]` (notice the "sl/" part) and now I just get:

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

I want everything to work if I type the name of my page in the URL field, I also wish to write .htaccess in a way that the application will ignore /sl/ part in my URL